# How to show relational columns in grid using APYDataGridBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid

I use APYDataGridBundle for generating a data table.

I have Person entity with a relation (1 gym can have more people):

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gym", inversedBy="persons")
 */
private $gym;
```

I generate a grid with a list of people in controller:

```php
public function indexAction(Grid $grid)
{
    // Creates a simple grid based on your entity (ORM)
    $source = new Entity(Person::class);

    $grid->setSource($source);

    return $grid->getGridResponse('Person/index.html.twig');
```

It shows me the grid with all non-relational columns, but the gym column not, because of the relation.

I can't find the solution in doc: https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/summary.md

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Person entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gym", inversedBy="persons")
     *
     * @GRID\Column(field="gym.id", title="Gym ID")
     * @GRID\Column(field="gym.title", title="Gym Title")
     */
    private $gym;
```